# Run Azure powershell commands in Azure devops pipeline

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

[image]What I should do to run the Azure powershell commands against release pipeline. When i try to run the Azure powershell command in the "Inline Azure Powershell" i am getting below error.

```
##[error]The term 'Get-AzKeyVaultSecret' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

I am using Hosted agent provided by the Azure pipeline

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There has 2 method.

Suggest you use **Azure Powershell Task** and change to **Inline** type.

First method is change the **Azure Powershell Task** version to `4.*`. In `4.*`, we **build-in** the `Az.KeyVault` module. And it will download the corresponding dll to support this command use.

[image]

---

Or you can continue to use `1.*` version task. Just run

`Install-Module Az.KeyVault`

command firstly to prepare the environment.

Comment: After adding Install-Module Az.KeyVault

I am getting a different error
#[error]Neither the Azure module nor the AzureRM module was found. If the module was recently installed, retry after restarting the VSTS task agent.

Comment: @tjdoubts, Are you still using 1.* version? Because it lacking the azure module and the azure RM module. These 2 modules are the basic of other feature module. I strongly suggest you use 4.* version which we pre-build in almost all basic modules(you don't need to install-module again). Or use 1.* task and run Install-Module command to prepare all basic and feature environments.

Comment: For me it is showing only Task Version 1.* . How to update task version

Comment: @tjdoubts. Seems you are using an extension task to run the line powershell? Why not using Azure powershell task(provided officially), and select the Script Type as inline?

Comment: @tjdoubts. Welcome:-) So it is succeed on your side now? If yes, appreciate for accept this answer

Comment: One more thing 
when i try to print the (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -vaultName "keyvalultname" -name "DBPassword").SecretValueText in the Pipeline not getting the value whereas the same command is printing correctly in the local environment. What else i have to do in the pipeline to get the correct vaule

Comment: When i try to print the (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -vaultName "keyvalultname" -name "DBPassword").SecretValueText in the Pipeline not getting the value whereas the same command is printing correctly in the local environment. What else i have to do in the pipeline to get the correct vaule

Comment: @tjdoubts, seems relevant with write-output. What about using `Write-Host` to print out ?

Comment: No i am not getting it printed by any means

Comment: @tjdoubts Sorry about delay because of my personal work. still nothing showed by using Write-Host in VSTS task?

Comment: i posted new question for this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59250555/not-able-to-print-the-azure-keyvault-secret-in-the-release-pipeline