# Can key vault secrets be retrieved and retained by a pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-keyvault

I have an API Token that I am storing in an Azure Key Vault. I want to provide access to this *secret* so it can be used from various pipelines. But I don't necessarily want anyone editing/executing those pipelines to be able to retain the Token. If a pipeline just `echo`es the [secret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59250555/not-able-to-print-the-azure-keyvault-secret-in-the-release-pipeline) value then won't the build agent logs simply display it, making the whole key vault process a useless step?
If that is the case, is there a way to safeguard a value if I don't necessarily want to trust everyone that can create pipelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the secret is being retrieved and turned into a variable. In general, secrets retrieved via the standard Azure Pipelines tasks will be masked as `****` when being displayed.

However, there's nothing to stop someone malicious from base64 encoding the value and printing it. Or ROT encoding it. Or reversing it. Or splitting the string in half and printing both halves. Or running a script that does this: `az keyvault secret show`. And so on and so forth.

If there's a secret value in memory as plain text, and people have the ability to manipulate the environment on which the secret is stored in memory as plain text, it's trivial to get the plaintext value of the secret. That's true for any computer under any circumstances.

If this is a concern, by far the best approach is to not have pipelines read secrets. If your application can be configured to integrate directly with keyvault and retrieve the secrets as needed at runtime, there's no need to have the pipeline retrieve the secret as an intermediate step.